# Android app code to access webstite

Tags: android, web

I'm looking to write an android app that will call a fun little script I made on my computer. when I open the script in my web browser, the computer will run the "beep" command. How would I do this from inside an android app so that when I press a button it'll call the website and beep my comuputer? I've tried this, but it didn't seem to work for me.

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
    "http://www.blah.com/beep.php");
```

More info:
The code I'm running on the server:

```
beeping!
<?php
shell_exec("beep -f 2000 -r 3 -l 100 -d 20"); ?>
```

I'm running the app that has a button that calls the beep method.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
} //here is the error that says i need to remove this token

new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run(){
    try{
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
        "http://www.blah.com/beep.php");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      throw e;
  }}
}).start();
} //here is the error to insert } to complete classbody
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
        "http://www.blah.com/beep.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch(Exception x) {
        ...
    }}
}).start();
```

Comment: For some reason this code makes Eclipse think there's a syntax error where it needs a } to complete classbody and that I need to delete a token... I'll post my full android code

Comment: Put the same inside some function, same as you did with your code.

Comment: Ok, now it doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't make the server beep. the only thing in the log that showed up was the Choreographer saying it skipped 123 times...

Comment: do i need the onclick to be beep.run or something? I've got it set as "beep", i put the new runnable in a void called beep.

Comment: [2013-05-24 17:07:08 - Beep] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front